# How to scrape google maps to find bodies of water?

Tags: java, r, google-maps, web-scraping

I have been learning how to scrape google maps and have been wondering how to write a code that would make the distinction between bodies of water and land. I have been coding in r and have found packages that could be useful, such as ‘RgoogleMaps’, but I have no idea how to implement them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "if a piece of land is a body of water or not" - sounds kind of contradictory. What do you mean exactly? Rivers? Lakes?

Comment: I want to make a code that can find any type of water on the map. Also edited so it was a bit more clear, sorry.

Comment: So including oceans. Must it be able to say "Ocean, Lake, River" or just general "body of water"? And have you thought about resolution? You won't want to detect a puddle as "body of water" , right?

Comment: Nope, just "body of water".

Comment: For the most part I wouldn't mind that. I am trying to track misquotes breeding areas and any water would qualify it to be just that.

Comment: Too bad I cannot be of much help due my lack of knowledge in r. But I wish all the luck. It is a very interesting project. So I give you +1 for promotion. You may update the question to include the info I asked for and elaborate what you want to do and what you already tried.